# how to get top 3 values in php array and their index

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, max

I want to get the highest value, the second highest value and the third highest value

For example, I have an array like:

`$n = array(100,90,150,200,199,155,15,186);`

I know the method to get the max value and its index:

`echo max($n); //200
$maxs = array_keys($n, max($n));
echo $maxs[0]; //3`

I want to get the top 3 values and their index like : value: 200, 199, 186  index:3,4,7

How can i get them?

Comment: start by using [asort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)

Comment: I find an answer for myself

`
$n = array(100,90,150,200,199,186,15,155);
$a = $n;
sort($n);
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
echo $n[sizeof($n)-1-$i].'-';
$index[$i] = array_search($n[sizeof($n)-1-$i], $a);
echo $index[$i].',';
}`

output:200-3,199-4,186-5,

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$n = array(100,90,150,200,199,155,15,186);
rsort($n);
$top3 = array_slice($n, 0, 3);
echo 'Values: ';
foreach ($top3 as $key => $val) {
 echo "$val\n";
}
echo '<br>';
echo 'Keys: ';
foreach ($top3 as $key => $val) {
echo "$key\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
Values: 200 199 186 
Keys: 0 1 2
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
function maxNitems($array, $n = 3){
    asort($array);
    return array_slice(array_reverse($array, true),0,$n, true);
}
```

Use like:

```
maxNitems(array(100,90,150,200,199,155,15,186));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using `arsort()` and `array_keys()` functions:

- `arsort()` sorts an array in reverse order and maintains index association
- `array_keys()` returns all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array

Process array:

```
$n = array(100,90,150,200,199,155,15,186);
arsort($n);
$keys = array_keys($n);
```

Get top 3 values:

```
echo $n[$keys[0]];
echo $n[$keys[1]];
echo $n[$keys[2]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$n = array(100,90,150,200,199,155,15,186);
arsort($n);

$x = 0;
while (++$x <= 3)
{
    $key = key($n);
    $value = current($n);
    next($n);
    echo "Key : " . $key . " Value  : " . $value . '<br>' ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier I would think:

```
arsort($n);
$three = array_chunk($n, 3, true)[0];
//or
$three = array_slice($n, 0, 3, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public function getTopSortedThree(array $data, $asc = true)
{
    if ($asc) {
        uasort($data, function ($a, $b) { return $a>$b;});
    } else {
        uasort($data, function ($a, $b) { return $a<$b;});
    }
    $count = 0;
    $result = [];
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $result[] = $data[$key];
        $count++;
        if ($count >= 3){
            break;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

send `false` for `desc` order and nothing for `asc` order

This functionality doesn't losing keys.